# r - dplyr mutate refer new column itself

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame like this named 'a'.

```
   ID        V1
   1         -1 
   1          0 
   1          1 
   1        1000 
   1          0 
   1          1
   2         -1 
   2          0 
   2         1000 


...
```

I shorten this data frame to show briefly.

And now I want to create a new column using conditional mutate function, but it should refer new column created by mutate function.

```
a %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
    mutate(V2, ifelse(row_number() == 1, 1, 
      ifelse(V1 < 1000, 1,
      ifelse(V1 >= 1000, lag(V2) + 1))
```

"Error: Then 'V2' not found" message is produced.

This result is what I want.

```
   ID        V1       V2
   1         -1       1
   1          0       1
   1          1       1
   1        1000      2
   1          0       2
   1          1       2
   2         -1       1
   2          0       1
   2         1000     2
```

How to I get this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `lag(V1)`?

Comment: No, It refers V2 itself.

Comment: So, what you want is: for each id, V2 will add up by 1 when V1 is equal or higher than 1000?

Comment: @zyurnaidi Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try

```
a %>%
     group_by(ID) %>% 
     mutate(V2 = cumsum(V1 >= 1000)+1L)
#     ID    V1    V2
#  <int> <int> <int>
#1     1    -1     1
#2     1     0     1
#3     1     1     1
#4     1  1000     2
#5     1     0     2
#6     1     1     2
#7     2    -1     1
#8     2     0     1
#9     2  1000     2
```

#### data

```
a <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
V1 = c(-1L, 
0L, 1L, 1000L, 0L, 1L, -1L, 0L, 1000L)), .Names = c("ID", "V1"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: @LuisKang I was using only your example dataset.  If you have loaded `plyr` along with `dplyr`, you could try `dplyr::mutate(V2=...`

Comment: It works as I changed cumsum(V1==1000) to cumsum(V1>=1000). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
a %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(V2 = ifelse(row_number() == 1, 1, 0) + 
                                ifelse(row_number() > 1 & V1 <= 1000, 1, 0) + 
                                cumsum(ifelse(V1 >= 1000, 1, 0)))
```

Update: Changed second ifelse logic statement from **row_number() > 1 & V1 < 1000** to that shown above. *This alteration should give the results as requested in the comments.*

Comment: This answer seems to work well. But the result is (V1 = 1000 & V2 = 1) and then next V2 = 2. I want (V1 = 1000 & V2 = 2) right away.

Comment: You could use **row_number() > 1 & V1 <= 1000** in the second _ifelse_ statement, that should fix it. I will update my answer.