# How can I recursively refer to a mutated column?

Tags: r, excel

I am attempting to use conditional logic to fill the mutated values in a column with a value in the same row in another column if it is one of three strings, and if not, to use the value in the row above.

I was able to create an excel function that does exactly what I need, but am unable to repeat the same function in R. The excel function works because the data is already pre-sorted, so a similar approach should work in R.

Input:

```
StateDeterminationId, PrimaryRecordType
740494, Success
44808,  To_be_worked_PDF
1018734,    Success
1037934,    Dupe
1047721,    Dupe
1056517,    Dupe
1069024,    Dupe
741064, Success
1013044,    Success
1027308,    Dupe
```

Output:

```
StateDeterminationId,   PrimaryRecordType,  PrimaryRecordNumber
740494, Success,    740494
44808,  To_be_worked_PDF,   44808
1018734,    Success,    1018734
1037934,    Dupe,   1018734
1047721,    Dupe,   1018734
1056517,    Dupe,   1018734
1069024,    Dupe,   1018734
741064, Success,    741064
1013044,    Success,    1013044
1027308,    Dupe,   1013044
```

Excel function:

```
=IF(OR(R2="Success", R2="To_be_worked_PDF", R2="To_be_worked_no_PDF"), A2,S1)
```

R Function:

```
csv %>% mutate(test_column = case_when(row_number() == 1 ~ StateDeterminationId, row_number() != 1 & (PrimaryRecordType == "Success" | PrimaryRecordType == "To_be_worked_PDF" | PrimaryRecordType == "To_be_worked_PDF") ~ StateDeterminationId, PrimaryRecordType == "Dupe" ~ lag(test_column, 1)))
```

The error message I am getting is that `test_column` doesn't exist. I believe this is a result of `test_column` not being created in row 1, which was why I added `row_number()` per [r - dplyr mutate refer new column itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340964/r-dplyr-mutate-refer-new-column-itself). This does not seem to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

There are other, more tidy ways you could solve this problem.  For example:

```
csv %>% 
    mutate(test_column = ifelse(StateDeterminationId == 1 | PrimaryRecordType != 'Dupe', StateDeterminationId, NA)) %>% 
    fill("test_column", .direction = "down")
```

Comment: Just note that based on your sample input, better to use `read_csv` to have whitespace trimmed before comparing with `'Dupe'`. If column `PrimaryRecordType` is a factor (although which shouldn't be based on your sample input), you might also need `as.character(PrimaryRecordType)` before comparison.