# dplyr / base R: compute new columns using logic combinations of row indices

Tags: r, indexing, dplyr

I analyse a data set from an experiment and would like to calculate effect sizes for each variable. My dataframe consist of multiple variables (= columns) for 8 treatments t (= rows), with t1 - t4 being the control for t5 - t8, respectively (t1 control for t5, t2 for t6, ... ). The original data set is way larger, so I would like to solve the following two tasks::

1. I would like to calculate the log(treatment/control) for each t5 - t8 for one variable, e.g. effect size for t5 = log(t5/t1), effect size for t6 = log(t6/t2), ... . The name of the resulting column should be variablename_effect and the new column would only have 4 rows instead of 8.
   The most tricky part is, that I need to implement the combination of specific rows into my code, so that the correct control is used for each treatment.
2. I would like to calculate the effect sizes for all my variables within one code, so create multiple new columns with the correct names (variablename_effect).

I would prefer to solve the problem in dplyr or base R to keep it simple.
So far, the only related question I found was [/r-dplyr-mutate-refer-new-column-itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37340964/r-dplyr-mutate-refer-new-column-itself) (shows combination of multiple `if else()`). I would be very thankful for either a solution, links to similar questions or which packages I should use in cast it's not possible within dplyr / base R!

**Sample data:**

```
df <- data.frame("treatment" = c(1:8), "Var1" = c(9:16), "Var2" = c(17:24))
```

Edit: this is the df_effect I would expect to receive as an output, thanks @Martin_Gal for the hint!

```
df_effect <- data.frame("treatment" = c(5:8), "Var1_effect" = c(log(13/9), log(14/10), log(15/11), log(16/12)), "Var2_effect" = c(log(21/17), log(22/18), log(23/19), log(24/20)))
```

**My ideas so far:**

1. For calculating the effect size:

mutate() and for function:

```
# 1st option:
for (i in 5:8) {
dt_effect <- df %>%
  mutate(Var1_effect = log(df[i, "Var1"]/df[i - 4, "Var1"]))
}
#2nd option:
for (i in 5:8){
dt_effect <- df %>%
mutate(Var1_effect = log(df[treatment == i , "Var1"]/df[treatment == i - 4 , "Var1"]))
}
```

problem: both return the result for i = 8 for every row!

mutate() and ifelse():

```
df_effect <- df %>%
  mutate(Var1_effect = ifelse(treatment >= 5, log(df[, "Var1"]/df[ , "Var1"]), NA))
```

seems to work, but so far I couldn't implement which row to pick for the control, so it returns NA for t1 - t4 (correct) and 0 for t5 - t8 (mathematically correct as I calculate log(t5/t5), ... but not what I want).

maybe I should use summarise() instead of mutate() because I create fewer rows than in my original dataframe?

2. Make this work for every variable at the same time

My only idea would be to index the columns within a second for function and use the paste() to create the new column names, but I don't know exactly how to do this ...

Comment: Based on your example data.frame: Could you show how your expected output would look like?

Comment: If you add indicator variables for Type (= Treatment or Control) and Index (1:4) and then join the dataframe with itself so that Treatment and the corresponding control are in the same row, it strikes me that your problem will be much simpler.  As @MartinGal says, some ideas of your expected output would be helpful.

Comment: thanks for the hint @MartinGal - I added the expected output!

Comment: @Limey I thought of this as well, but I though it would acutally make my data untidy. All t1 - t8 are different experimental setups and it depends on the effect I am looking at which ones are the controls and which the treatments. That's why I could do it like this for this one effect mentioned above, but would have to create a new data.frames for each effect I look at (would work, but feels a bit like cheating)

Comment: The first draft of my comment started off "Your problem is that your data isn't tidy"!  But then I reread your post and saw that your data *could* be tidy.  We are in danger of a philosophical diversion.  Most of the time, "Control" is just another type of treatment, so your format is tidy and my suggestion isn't.  But when you want to calculate an effect, I think it's legitimate to regard "Control" as "Not-Treatment".  After all, when you present your "effects", you're going to drop "Control" rows, aren't you?  Their effects are all zero.  If being tidy makes my life difficult, I'll be messy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but I want to make a suggestion similar to Limey:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(control = 1 - (treatment-1) %/% (nrow(.)/2),
         group = ifelse(treatment %% (nrow(.)/2) == 0, nrow(.)/2, treatment %% (nrow(.)/2))) %>%
  select(-treatment) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(control), values_from=c(Var1, Var2)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(Var1_effect = log(Var1_0/Var1_1))
```

This yields

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Groups:   group [4]
  group Var1_1 Var1_0 Var2_1 Var2_0 Var1_effect
  <dbl>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>       <dbl>
1     1      9     13     17     21       0.368
2     2     10     14     18     22       0.336
3     3     11     15     19     23       0.310
4     4     12     16     20     24       0.288
```

What happend here?

- I expected the first half of your data.frame to be the control variables for the second half. So I created an indicator variable and a grouping variable based on the treatment id's/numbers.
- Now the treatment id isn't used anymore, so I dropped it.
- Next I used `pivot_wider` to create a dataset with `Var1_1` (i.e. `Var1` for your control variable) and `Var1_0` (i.e. `Var1` for your "ordinary" variable).
- Finally I calculated `Var1_effect` per group.

Comment: I think I have to read into the syntax before I really get how the code works :) 
As mentioned above, this will work perfectly fine for the effect mentioned above where t1 - t4 are controls, but will be more difficult if I can't sort control and treatment as streight forward as it was possible here ... . That's why I would prefer to use the indices if possible

Comment: Pretty much my solution, @Martin, though my code would have been longer because I would have explictly created Type and Index before joining the df with itself.  IMHO, that would be clearer, but at the expense of length.  Your code is compact and effective, so which is better is down to personal preference.  Both approaches work.

Comment: @Limey Thanks. Unfortunately that doesn't solve OPs problem. :-( ATM I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: @Limey if it's not too much effort, I would be interested in seeing your code as well - it might help to understand MartinGals elegant version :)

Answer (score 0):

In response to OP's comment to @MartinGal 's solution (which is perfectly fione in its own right):

First convert the input data to a more convenient form:

```
# Original input dataset
df <- data.frame("treatment" = c(1:8), "Var1" = c(9:16), "Var2" = c(17:24))
# Revised input dataset
revisedDF <- df %>% 
               select(-treatment) %>% 
               add_column(
                 Treatment=rep(c("Control", "Test"), each=4), 
                 Experiment=rep(1:4, times=2)
               ) %>%
             pivot_longer(
               names_to="Variable", 
               values_to="Value", 
               cols=c(Var1, Var2)
             ) %>% 
             arrange(Experiment, Variable, Treatment)
revisedDF %>% head(6)
```

Giving

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Treatment Experiment Variable Value
  <chr>          <int> <chr>    <int>
1 Control            1 Var1         9
2 Test               1 Var1        13
3 Control            1 Var2        17
4 Test               1 Var2        21
5 Control            2 Var1        10
6 Test               2 Var1        14
```

I like this format because it makes the analysis code completely independent of the number of variables, the number of experiements and the number of Treatments.

The analysis is straightforward, too:

```
result <- revisedDF %>% pivot_wider(
                          names_from=Treatment,
                          values_from=Value
                        ) %>% 
                        mutate(Effect=log(Test/Control))
result
```

Giving

```
  Experiment Variable Control  Test Effect
       <int> <chr>      <int> <int>  <dbl>
1          1 Var1           9    13  0.368
2          1 Var2          17    21  0.211
3          2 Var1          10    14  0.336
4          2 Var2          18    22  0.201
5          3 Var1          11    15  0.310
6          3 Var2          19    23  0.191
7          4 Var1          12    16  0.288
8          4 Var2          20    24  0.182
```

`pivot_wider` and `pivot_longer` are relatively new `dplyr` verbs.  If you're unable to use the most recent version of the package, `spread` and `gather` do the same job with slightly different argument names.